# Is this lazy-loading cache implementation thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing with the 3.5 .NET Framework and I need to use a cache in a multithread scenario with lazy-loading pattern for its items.
After reading several articles on the web I've tried to write my own implementation.

```
public class CacheItem
{
    public void ExpensiveLoad()
    {
        // some expensive code
    }
}
public class Cache
{
    static object SynchObj = new object();
    static Dictionary<string, CacheItem> Cache = new Dictionary<string, CacheItem>();
    static volatile List<string> CacheKeys = new List<string>();

    public CacheItem Get(string key)
    {
        List<string> keys = CacheKeys;
        if (!keys.Contains(key))
        {
            lock (SynchObj)
            {
                keys = CacheKeys;
                if (!keys.Contains(key))
                {
                    CacheItem item = new CacheItem();
                    item.ExpensiveLoad();
                    Cache.Add(key, item);
                    List<string> newKeys = new List<string>(CacheKeys);
                    newKeys.Add(key);
                    CacheKeys = newKeys;
                }
            }
        }
        return Cache[key];
    }
}
```

As you can see the Cache object uses both a dictionary which stores the real key-value pairs and a list which duplicates only the keys.
When a thread calls the Get method it reads the static shared key list (which is declared volatile) and call the Contains method to see if the key is already present and if not uses a double-checked lock pattern before starting the lazy loading. At the end of the loading a new instance of the key list is created and stored in the static variable.

Obviously I'm in a situation where the cost of recreating the entire list of keys is almost irrelevant against the cost of a single item loading.

I hope someone can tell me if it is really thread-safe.
When I say "thread-safe" I mean that every reader thread can avoid corrupted or dirty reads and every writer thread loads the missing item only once.

Comment: Did you look at ReaderWriterLock ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx

Comment: @Kip9000: That class has been practically deprecated in favor of [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx).

Comment: @Jon My mistake, I meant to write ReaderWriterLockSlim. ReaderWriterLock doesn't seem deprecated but preferred and much better according to MSDN.

Comment: I think the use of `lock()` even eliminates the need for volatile, at least under the normal CLR.

Comment: As it stands, if the element is in the Cache (keys.Contains(key) returns true) you always return null!  Personally I'd recommend you get hold of the source of the .NET4 ConcurrentDictionary and use that.

Comment: Yes when I realized this I immediatly edit and fix it.

Comment: Yes when I realized this I immediatly edit and fix it.

Comment: You trade two O(n) lookups for a lock.  That can only pay off for trivial lists, no more than a handful of cached items.  At least use a HashSet.  And time it.

Comment: Well in most cases there will be only a lookup on the key list and no lock when the item has already been created. Even if I put all the code inside the lock I'll always have to do one lookup on the Dictionary to know if the key is already present. Isn't it true?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The code isn't thread safe, so what `volatile` offers at all is in question, let alone in conjunction with `lock`...

Comment: Why not use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ContainsKey` instead of tracking the keys separately?

Answer (score 7):

This is not thread safe since you aren't locking when reading the Dictionary.

There is a race condition whereby one thread can be reading:

```
return Cache[key];
```

while another is writing:

```
_Cache.Add(key, item);
```

As the [MSDN documentation for `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) states: `

> To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

and your synchorization does not include the reader.

You really need to use a thread-safe dictionary, which will simplify your code enormously (you won't need the List at all)

I'd recommend getting the source for the .NET 4 ConcurrentDictionary.

Getting thread safety right is hard, as is evidenced by the fact that some of the other answerers are incorrectly stating that your implementation is thread-safe.  Hence I'd trust Microsoft's implementation before a home made one.

If you don't want to use a thread-safe dictionary, then I'd recommend something simple like:

```
public CacheItem Get(string key)
{
    lock (SynchObj)
    {
        CacheItem item;
        if (!Cache.TryGetValue(key, out item))
        {
            item = new CacheItem();
            item.ExpensiveLoad();
            Cache.Add(key, item);
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

You could also try an implementation with a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, though you might not get a significant performance improvement (google for ReaderWriterLockSlim performance).

As for an implementation using a ConcurrentDictionary, in most cases I would simply use something like:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheItem> Cache = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheItem>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
...
CacheItem item = Cache.GetOrAdd(key, key => ExpensiveLoad(key));
```

This can result in `ExpensiveLoad` being called more that once for each key, but I bet if you profile your app you'll find that this is so rare as to not be a problem.

If you really insist on ensuring it's only called once, then you could get hold of the .NET 4 `Lazy<T>` implementation and do something like:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<CacheItem>> Cache = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<CacheItem>>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
...

CacheItem item = Cache.GetOrAdd(key, 
               new Lazy<CacheItem>(()=> ExpensiveLoad(key))
             ).Value;
```

In this version, multiple `Lazy<CacheItem>` instances might be created, but only one will actually be stored in the dictionary.  `ExpensiveLoad` will be called the first time `Lazy<CacheItem>.Value` is dereferenced for the instance stored in the dictionary.
This `Lazy<T>` constructor uses LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication which uses a lock internally so ensure only one thread calls the factory method `ExpensiveLoad`.

As an aside, when constructing any dictionary with a string key, I always use the `IEqualityComparer<string>` parameter (usually StringComparer.Ordinal or StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) to explicitly document the intention regarding case-sensitivity.

Comment: My first version of the code did not end with the `return Cache[key];` statement so maybe was really thread-safe, but was buggy because it always returned null in case of cache hit. So I edited and modified adding the thread-safety issue.

Comment: replacing `Dictionary` with `ConcurrentDictionary` wouldn't make it thread-safe.  `ContainsKey` would be thread-safe; but there's still the distinct possibility that `CacheKeys` changes between the assignment to `keys` and the call to `ContainsKeys`.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, I didn't say that replacing Dictionary with ConcurrentDictionary would make this implementation thread-safe.  I said ConcurrentDictionary would enable him to simplify his code enormously and get rid of the list.  I'll leave the full implementation as an exercise, or for another answerer to provide.

Comment: @Joe well, the question was about whether the code is thread-safe; so, I assumed that any answer would be addressing that.  You don't detail *how* `ConcurrentDictionary` is different from `Dictionary` in such a way as to distinctly result in not needing a `List<T>`.  For example, `Dictionary<T1, T2>` has `ContainsKey` method so you can check `Dictionary` for keys without using a `List<T>`.  So, it's not clear how `ConcurrentDictionary` would distinctly be different than that.

Comment: @Joe The "simple" version would certainly be thread safe but I had a really hope to find a solution that would not lock on every call to the `Get` method. But I have the suspect it is not on the way.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, "I assumed that any answer would be addressing that" - my answer does address that, it states that the code is not thread-safe, and says why.

Comment: @user1667010, I don't see any way to avoid taking at least a read lock on every call.  And bringing in a List adds complexity, and is likely slower (you are doing an O(n) lookup of the key in the list on every call, as opposed to an O(1) key lookup in the dictionary).

Comment: @Joe Fair enough; but it does miss some reasons why it's not thread safe and seems to introduce the non sequitur of `ConcurrentDictionary` ...

Comment: @PeterRitchie, it's not thread safe as I said because one thread is reading the dictionary while another is updating it.  The writer thread will be messing with the dictionary's internal structure (buckets and so on) which will cause the reader thread to go "boom" every now and again.  I've added a sample using the ConcurrentDictionary to make things more clear.  As the MSDN documentation for Dictionary<TKey,TValue> states: "To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization."

Comment: @Joe Of course using the lock at every call there is no more need to maintain the list of keys and I can access the Dictionary directly as you showed.

Comment: @user1667010, absolutely.  You need to synchronize access to the dictionary, so the list is superfluous.

Comment: @Joe I had also implemented a cache using ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<T>> in a case where my valueFactory had side effects. Using lazies enabled me to ensure that each side effect ran only once. It's good advice!

Answer (score 0):

So far i can't see any big issues. The only thing i can't see in your code is how do you make the `CacheKeys` public? The simplest one would be as `IList<string>` which is filled by a `ReadOnlyCollection`. This way your consumers can use index operators or the count property quite easily. In this case the `volatile` keyword should also not be needed cause you already put everything into your lock. So i would pimp your class as follows:

```
public class CacheItem
{
    public void ExpensiveLoad()
    {
        // some expensive code
    }
}
public class Cache
{
    private static object _SynchObj = new object();
    private static Dictionary<string, CacheItem> _Cache = new Dictionary<string, CacheItem>();
    private static ReadOnlyCollection<string> _CacheKeysReadOnly = new ReadOnlyCollection(new List<string>());

    public IList<string> CacheKeys
    {
        get
        {
            return _CacheKeysReadOnly;
        }
    }

    public CacheItem Get(string key)
    {
        CacheItem item = null;
        ReadOnlyCollection<string> keys = _CacheKeysReadOnly;
        if (!keys.Contains(key))
        {
            lock (_SynchObj)
            {
                keys = _CacheKeysReadOnly;
                if (!keys.Contains(key))
                {
                    item = new CacheItem();
                    item.ExpensiveLoad();
                    _Cache.Add(key, item);
                    List<string> newKeys = new List<string>(_CacheKeysReadOnly);
                    newKeys.Add(key);
                    _CacheKeysReadOnly = newKeys.AsReadOnly();
                }
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

As an alternative if you already on .Net 4.5 you could also think about using the [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385) interface for the `CacheKeys` property.

Comment: The purpose of this cache is only to read elements and create them if don't exist. So for now I only need access thru the Get method. Anyway thanks for the advice. P.S. are you really sure I don't need the volatile keyword? There still are read calls on CacheKeys(witch I suppose would be static) outside the lock.

Comment: @user1667010: Their will be reads, but nobody can change the list, it is read-only. So we have an immutable list and and it only be exchanged against a new list, when the new list is ready (and boxed as read-only). The worst thing that could happen is that a consumer gets an old list (when accessing the public property) where the recently added item is not available, but that could already happened beforehand too, regardless if you use volatile or not. For the `Get()` method the `volatile` is not needed cause you already have the lock-statement.

Comment: `_CacheKeysReadOnly` can still change between the assignment to `keys` and the call to `keys.Contains(key)` on another thread.  This is no more thread-safe than the original.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: But for this case the `lock` takes care and the second assignment and lookup of `keys`.