# A multithreading implementation of a lazy-loaded cache with known key list

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'm developing a multithread application with .Net 3.5 that reads records from different tables stored in a database. The readings are very frequent so there is the need of a lazy loading caching implementation. Every table is mapped to a C# class and has a string column that can be used as key in the cache. 
In addition there is the requirement that periodically all the cached records should be refreshed.
I could have implemented the cache with a lock on every reading to ensure a thread-safe environment, but then I thought another solution that rely on the fact that it is simple to get a list of all possible keys.

So here is the first class I wrote, that stores the list of all the keys that is lazy loaded with the double checked lock pattern. It also has a method that stores in a static variable the timestamp of the last requested refresh.

```
public class Globals
{
    private static object _KeysLock = new object();
    public static volatile List<string> Keys;
    public static void LoadKeys()
    {
        if (Keys == null)
        {
            lock (_KeysLock)
            {
                if (Keys == null)
                {
                    List<string> keys = new List<string>();
                    // Filling all possible keys from DB
                    // ...
                    Keys = keys;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static long refreshTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToBinary();
    public static DateTime RefreshTimeStamp
    {
        get { return DateTime.FromBinary(Interlocked.Read(ref refreshTimeStamp)); }
    }
    public static void NeedRefresh()
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref refreshTimeStamp, DateTime.Now.ToBinary());
    }
}
```

Then I wrote the `CacheItem<T>` class that is the implementation of a single item of the cache for a specified table T filtered by the key. It has the `Load` method for the record list lazy-loading and the `LoadingTimeStamp` property that stores the timestamp of the last record loading. Please note that the static list of records is overwritten with the new one that is locally filled and then the `LoadingTimeStamp` is overritten too.

```
public class CacheItem<T>
{
    private List<T> _records;
    public List<T> Records
    {
        get { return _records; }
    }

    private long loadingTimestampTick;
    public DateTime LoadingTimestamp
    {
        get { return DateTime.FromBinary(Interlocked.Read(ref loadingTimestampTick)); }
        set { Interlocked.Exchange(ref loadingTimestampTick, value.ToBinary()); }
    }

    public void Load(string key)
    {
        List<T> records = new List<T>();
        // Filling records from DB filtered on key
        // ...
        _records = records;
        LoadingTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

And finally here is the `Cache<T>` class that stores the cache for the table T as a static Dictionary. As you can see the `Get` method first loads all possible keys in the cache if not already done and then checks the timestamps for the refresh (both are done with the double checked lock pattern). The list of record in the instance returned by a `Get` call can safely be read by a thread even if there is another thread that is doing the refresh inside the lock, because the refreshing thread does not modify the list itself but creates a new one.

```
public class Cache<T>
{
    private static object _CacheSynch = new object();
    private static Dictionary<string, CacheItem<T>> _Cache = new Dictionary<string, CacheItem<T>>();
    private static volatile bool _KeysLoaded = false;

    public static CacheItem<T> Get(string key)
    {
        bool checkRefresh = true;
        CacheItem<T> item = null;
        if (!_KeysLoaded)
        {
            lock (_CacheSynch)
            {
                if (!_KeysLoaded)
                {
                    Globals.LoadKeys(); // Checks the lazy loading of the common key list
                    foreach (var k in Globals.Keys)
                    {
                        item = new CacheItem<T>();
                        if (k == key)
                        {
                            // As long as the lock is acquired let's load records for the requested key
                            item.Load(key);
                            // then the refresh is no more needed by the current thread
                            checkRefresh = false;
                        }
                        _Cache.Add(k, item);
                    }
                    _KeysLoaded = true;
                }
            }
        }
        // here the key is certainly contained in the cache
        item = _Cache[key];
        if (checkRefresh)
        {
            // let's check the timestamps to know if refresh is needed
            DateTime rts = Globals.RefreshTimeStamp;
            if (item.LoadingTimestamp < rts)
            {
                lock (_CacheSynch)
                {
                    if (item.LoadingTimestamp < rts)
                    {
                        // refresh is needed
                        item.Load(key);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Periodically the `Globals.NeedRefresh()` is called to ensure the records will be refreshed.
This solution can avoid a lock on every reading of the cache because the cache is pre-filled with all the possible keys: this means that there will be in memory a number of instances that is equal to the number of all possible keys (about 20) for each requested type T (all the T types are about 100), but only for the requested keys the record lists are not empty.
Please let me know if this solution has some thread-safety issue or anything wrong.
Thank you very mutch.

Comment: There's a slew of [Concurrent Containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718.aspx) in .NET you can use. These are already thread-safe, saving you from having to make it thread safe. Would this not make your life simpler?

Comment: He said he was using C#3.5 and the concurrent collections have been introduced with 4.0....

Comment: If I am correct you will only retrieve the keys once and load them individually when needed. What happens when new keys are inserted into the database? They will never be loaded?

Comment: @IvoTops The operation of adding new keys is rare and when happens the application will certainly be restarted, so this is not a problem. Actually the application is restarted every night.

Comment: @TonyTheLion I know the existence of those Concurrent Containers in .NET 4.0, but for the moment it is not possible to upgrade and we just can use .NET 3.5. Thanx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Given that:

- You load all keys once and never change them
- You create each dictionary once and never change it
- CacheItem.Load is thread-safe because it only ever replaces a private `List<T>` field with a new completely initialized list.

you don't need any locks at all, so could simplify the code.

The only possible need for a lock is to prevent concurrent attempts to run `CacheItem.Load`.  Personally I'd just let the concurrent database accesses run, but if you want to prevent it, you could just implement a lock in `CacheItem.Load`.  Or pinch `Lazy<T>` from .NET 4 and use that as suggested in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12403440/13087).

Another comment is that your refresh logic uses `DateTime.Now` so won't behave as expected (a) during the period when the clocks go back at the end of Daylight Saving Time and (b) if the system clock is updated.

I would simply use a static integer value that is incremented each time `NeedRefresh`is called.

From comments:

> What happens for example if two threads ... try to load the common Globals.Keys at the same time?"

There is a small risk that this may happen once at application startup, but so what?  It will result in the 20 keys being read from the database twice, but the performance impact is likely to be negligible.  And if you really want to prevent this, any locking could be encapsulated in a class like `Lazy<T>`.

> The comment about using DateTime.Now is in fact a point of interest but I think maybe I can suppose those events can occur while the application is not in use.

You can "suppose" that, but not guarantee it.  Your machine may decide to synchronize it's time with a time server at any time.

> About the advice of using an integer in NeedRefresh I don't understand how can I compare it with each record list state which is represented by a DateTime.

As far as I can see, you only use the `DateTime` to check if your data was loaded before or after the most recent call to `NeedRefresh`.  So you could replace this by:

```
public static class Globals
{
    ...

    public static int Version { get {return _version; } }
    private static int _version;

    public static void NeedRefresh()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _version);
    }
}

public class CacheItem<T>
{
    public int Version {get; private set; }

    ...

    public void Load(string key)
    {
        Version = Globals.Version;

        List<T> records = new List<T>();
        // Filling records from DB filtered on key
        // ...
        _records = records;
    }
}
```

then when accessing the cache:

```
item = _Cache[key];
if (item.Version < Globals.Version) item.Load();
```

** UPDATE 2 **

In response to comment:

> ... There could be a real risk of integrity if one thread tries to read the Dictionary while another is adding items to it inside the lock, couldn't be?

Your existing code adds all keys to the dictionary once only immediately after loading the global keys, and subsequently never modifies the dictionary.  So this is thread-safe as long as you don't assign the _Cache property until the dictionary is completely constructed:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, CacheItem<T>>(Global.Keys.Count);
foreach (var k in Globals.Keys)                       
{                           
    dictionary.Add(k, new CacheItem<T>());
}
_Cache = dictionary;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why you said I don't need any locks? In my opinion all the doubled-checked locks are necessary in order to obtain a real lazy loading pattern and be sure all the loadings will be done only once. What happens for example if two threads calling the `Get` method on different tables T try to load the common `Globals.Keys` at the same time? And the same is when two threads inside the `Get` method on the same table T try to pre-fill the keys in the common `Dictionary`. Am I wrong? (continue on next comment...)

Comment: The comment about using `DateTime.Now` is in fact a point of interest but I think maybe I can suppose those events can occur while the application is not in use. About the advice of using an integer in `NeedRefresh` I don't understand how can I compare it with each record list state which is represented by a DateTime

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciate your advices. I still have a question about the needing of locks. I understand that a concurrent loading of the key list would not be a real problem and can only happens at the sturtup, but what about the 100 Dictionary (one per table) ? There could be a real risk of integrity if one thread tries to read the Dictionary while another is adding items to it inside the lock, couldn't be?